# How to get the Astronomically Low Odds achievement?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

This achievement is: "*Fail to evade 5 shots in a row with a full powered and upgraded engine.*"

What is the best way to get the achievement?
Can I increase the posibilities by not using a manned engine and using low experienced crew members?
Can it be obteinable by using the auto-pilot (and then reducing the chances to miss)?
What would be the best scenario to obtain this archievemnt and what would be the posibilities to get it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The best way to do this achievement is to find an encounter where the enemy has no way of hurting you. This is the same technique used to train crews but is much more difficult in this case as it can only be performed late, after you have full engines.

There is, however, one ship that is perfect for this- the Rebel Flagship.

Enter the fight with fully upgraded engines, at least 6 shields (3 layers), level 3 piloting system, a teleporter and a decent boarding crew. Begin the fight by boarding and destroying the missile launcher, the ion blaster and the halberd beam. Leave the lasers (middle-left) alone.

You now have an enemy armed only with a burst laser 2. It is impossible for them to break your 3 shields, repair their guns, flee or do anything at all. All you need to do is man the engines and piloting and wait for the 5 hits in a row- you don't even need to watch it.

Comment: Nice strategy with the Flagship! But if I'm not watching it how will I know if I got the achievement while I was away?

Comment: @SysDragon I hadn't considered that. I guess it's either a case of watch for the achievement or leave the game for so long the chance of not getting it is negligible.

Comment: @SysDragon: Hit shift+tab and see if it shows up in your achievement list.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Nope =/

Comment: FYI: I was in the way to try your Flagship strategy and I got the achievement while fighting another ship. Two single lasers and a harbard beam, so it seems that beams does not count towards the number of fails.

Comment: @SysDragon Which makes sense since beams can't be evaded.

Answer (score 5):

The chance to get this is not really astronomically low. Your dodge chance to complete this achievement would be 45%, 35% from the engines and another 10% from your pilot as long he gained no levels. This leaves 55% chance the attack hits. 0.55*0.55*0.55*0.55*0.55 = 0.05 = 5%.

You need to have a active pilot. Since pilots level up and increase the dodge rating you should try to get the autopilot system or have only a active pilot when the opponent is using missiles.

Obviously you should not build defense drones since a lower amount of missiles have the chance to be dodged as the drones shooting them happens first. Also it does not say you have to man

By upgrading the engines as fast as possible you increase the amount of possibilities this could happen so effectively raises the chance over time.

You should try to find ships that fire many bursts of low damage. Also a hull repair drone helps you last longer while trying to get this achievement.

Further more there is a possible bug with this achievement.

Taken from FTL wikia:

> As of Steam Version 1.03.3 for Windows, I was unable to get this
>   achievement without also upgrading the Piloting Sub-System to level 3.
>   This doesn't seem like it should be necessary, but I let the game run
>   for roughly 5 hours against an opponent with a Level 3 Burst Laser (5
>   shots), watched combat for about 30 minutes and  witnessed 5
>   non-dodged shots in a row many times, assumed many others happened
>   over the course of 4 to 5 hours while I was not watching, and could
>   not get this achievement. When I upgraded the Piloting Sub-System to
>   level 3, I got the achievement a few minutes later. This could very
>   well be a bug, but if you are having difficulty, you may want to try
>   upgrading the Piloting Sub-System.

Comment: It is required that the enemy shots missiles or it's valid any shot (including lasers, bombs and ion shots)?

Comment: Actually now you ask i'm not sure. I was pretty sure it only counts missiles, probably bombs too. Can't really find reference to that either. I will investigate a bit more later when i'm not at work.

Comment: Lasers do seem to count, i'm not sure why i thought they would not. I will edit the answer when i have time.

Comment: Does it have to hit your actual ship, or does it count if it hits your shields?

Comment: A dodge is happening on the ship only. A laser can only be dodged when there are no shields. So in theory you are better off without shield.

Comment: A laser can be dodged whether you have shields or not. If you dodge it it doesn't hit your shields. Trying to do this without shields only makes it harder as you risk your systems getting damaged.

Comment: It has been some time i guess, might have been some updates ago too. After reading some additional info i came to the conclusion dodge is applied before shields. So shields should not be a problem getting this achievement.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to fully upgrade the engines and man the piloting station with an inexperienced crew member.
That's a 35%+5% = 40% dodge change.

Engines don't need to be manned.
Piloting station does not need to be upgraded.
Only using the autopilot does not work (assumption).

Since you have a 60% change of getting hit, the chance to get hit 5 times in a row is 7.8%.

I got it almost by mistake in the first fight after upgrading the engines. There was an asteroid field and the enemy ship had two combat drones.